# Any idea why I have to click the logout button twice to logout?

Tags: php, html, css, web-services, web

[This is my code for logout.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgnT.jpg)

When I click LOGOUT on my webpage I'm building, I have to click it twice to logout, any idea why?

Comment: code snippet not enough to debug why your logout is acting strange and use http://codepad.viper-7.com/ or http://pastebin.com/ when linking your code, :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you log out, the `if` is run through, destroying the session. Next time you log out, the `else` is run through, removing the cookies.

Look at [PHP - session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), there's an example on how to handle this.

You can also do this in one run, just do two independent `if`s

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) {
...
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) {
...
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Really tired. Probably should have went to bed. Didn't even see the else statement haha. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using both a session and a cookie, probably for a 'remember me' functionality. However, the logout script only deletes one at a time.

Try to remove the `else` in the `else if`.

```
if (session exists)
{
    destroy session
}

if (cookie exists)
{
    delete cookie
}
```